# Is there a formula for $\sum_k^{}{n - 2k \choose k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a formula for $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}{n - 2k \choose k}$$
$k$ ranges from $1$ to $\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor$ (so that $n - 2k \choose k$ makes sense combinatorially)

I tried to obtain a sum of Fibonacci numbers from the previous series but failed.

I am wondering if there is any identity that would help solve it or at least compress it to a simpler structure

Comment: [OEIS A000930](https://oeis.org/A000930)

Comment: this was surprisingly very helpful, thank you

Comment: Please add the summation range.

Comment: Are you summing on $n$, $k$, or both?

Comment: If $k$ is a nonnegative integer, $\binom{n-2k}k$ makes sense for all real or complex values of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a term $\binom n0=1$ for $k=0$ (so that you get one more than the value in the question), and terms equal to $0$ with either $k<0$ or $k>n-2k\geq0$, so as to minimize worries about the limits of the summation; the sum is then taken over over all $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that the upper index $n-2k$ is non negative. This means that Pascal's recurrence can be applied below to all terms except possibly one term with $n-2k=0$, but since $n>0$ one then has $k>0$, and such a term is $\binom0k=0$, and can be simply dropped before applying the recurrence.

Setting $a_n=\sum_k\binom{n-2k}k$, one has $a_n=1$ for $0\leq n<3$, while for $n\geq3$ one has by Pascal's recurrence
$$
  a_n=\sum_k\binom{n-2k}k
     =\sum_k\left(\binom{n-2k-1}k+\binom{n-2k-1}{k-1}\right)
   \\  =\sum_k\binom{n-2k-1}k+\sum_l\binom{n-2l-3}l = a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}
$$
This shows that this is indeed Narayana's cows sequence [OEIS A000930](https://oeis.org/A000930) mentioned in a comment.

Comment: What range of summation are you assuming? I get $$a_2=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2-2k}k=\binom20+\binom01+\binom{-2}2=1+0+3=4.$$